# Ubuntu 20.04 sound not working after fresh installation

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Recently, I changed my hard disk on my Dell XPS-L421X from HDD to SDD. So, I thought it would be a nice decision to just upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. However, after installation, no sound is coming out of the system. I am sorry if it seems that this question has been asked before. I have searched almost everywhere online, still no solution. 
I have run `sudo alsa force-reload`, still no result. I also ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio`. I edited this file as well `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, adding these two lines

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic 
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

I ran `aplay -l` and `lspci` commands, I get the result below

[image: image showing my sound configurations]

After several trials, in my pavucontrol, the only output device shown is the HDMI / Display port (Still no sound coming out).
[image: Pavucontrol output]

Could it be a hardware problem? maybe when the Engineer was removing the former HDD and replacing it with the SDD, some things were not properly coupled back?

Please, what can I do? I don't want to revert to 18.04. Thanks